# Is there an "easy" way to prove the general version Hall's Marriage Theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Hall's theorem:

> Suppose that $\mathcal{R}$ is a relation, $A=\mathrm{dom}(\mathcal{R})$ and $B=\mathrm{ran}(\mathcal{R})$ are finite, $h(A')=\{b\in B\mid \exists a\in A'\text{ such that } a\mathcal{R}b\}$ for $A'\subseteq A$, and that $|A'|\leq|h(A')|$ for all $A'\subseteq A$. Then there exists an injection $f:A\to B$ such that $f\subseteq\mathcal{R}$.

---

I have two questions regarding this theorem.

1. I have spent a week to give a shot, but I'm not sure if it contains error. Please check my below proof.

> We will prove this theorem by induction on $|A|$. It's clear that the theorem is true for $|A|=1$. Assume it is true for $|A|=n$. For $|A|=n+1$. Consider two cases.
>
> a. $|A'|<|h(A')|$ for all $A'\subseteq A$
>
> Let $A_1=A-\{a\}$ for some $a\in A$, and $b\in h(\{a\})$. Then $|A_1|=n$. For all $A'\subseteq A_1$, $|A'|<|h(A')|\leq|h(A')-\{b\}|+1$. So $|A'|\leq |h(A')-\{b\}|$. Since the theorem is true for $|A|=n$, there is an injection $f':A_1\to B-\{b\}$ such that $f'\subseteq\mathcal{R}$. Since $(a,b)\notin f'$ and $(a,b)\in\mathcal{R}$, $f=f'\cup\{(a,b)\}$ is the required function.
>
> b. There exists $\varnothing\neq A^{*}\subseteq A$ such that $|A^{*}|=|h(A^{*})|$
>
> Let $A_1=A-A^{*}$. We will prove that for all $A'\subseteq A_1,|A'|\leq |h(A')-h(A^{*})|$.
>
> Assume the contrary, there exists $A'\subseteq A_1$ such that $|A'|>|h(A')-h(A^{*})|$. Therefore, $|A'\cup A^{*}|=|A'|+|A^{*}|>|h(A')-h(A^{*})|+|h(A^{*})|=|(h(A')-h(A^{*}))\cup h(A^{*})|$ $=|h(A')\cup h(A^{*})|=|h(A'\cup A^{*})|.$ To sum up, $|A'\cup A^{*}|>|h(A'\cup A^{*})|$. This contradicts the fact that $|A'\cup A^{*}|\leq|h(A'\cup A^{*})|$ [Since $A'\cup A^{*}\subseteq A$].
>
> Thus for all $A'\subseteq A_1,|A'|\leq |h(A')-h(A^{*})|$. So there is an injection $f_1:A_1\to B-h(A^{*})$ such that $f_1\subseteq\mathcal{R}$. We also have an injection $f_2:A^{*}\to h(A^{*})$ such that $f_2\subseteq\mathcal{R}$. Since $f_1\cap f_2=\varnothing$, $f=f_1\cup f_2$ is the required function.

2. Is there any "easy" way to prove the more general version of this theorem in which $A$ is NOT necessarily finite, i.e. $A$ can be infinite.

I read one proof from https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hall%27s_Marriage_Theorem/General_Set and figured out one possible mistake ( I posted a thread to confirm this mistake at [Is this a mistake in the proof of Hall's Marriage Theorem from https://proofwiki.org?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813526/is-this-a-mistake-in-the-proof-of-halls-marriage-theorem-from-https-proofwiki), but have not received any answer).

Besides containing a *possible* error, the proof in that link appeals to Cowen-Engeler Lemma which appeals to Ultrafilter Lemma. I'm not exposed to any of these knowledge.

I would like to ask if there is any way to prove the more general version without using Cowen-Engeler Lemma or Ultrafilter Lemma.

Comment: As discussed in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234522/halls-theorem-vs-axiom-of-choice) question, there are models of ZF in which the general version of Hall's theorem is false for infinite sets, so it's likely that there's no way to prove this specific case without some form of choice (i.e. the ultrafilter lemma).

Comment: Thank you @JamesHanson, you solved my second question. Did you see any error in my proof?

Comment: I don't see any error in your proof.